# Why is Swift's ternary operator so picky about whitespace?

Tags: swift, operators, whitespace, option-type, conditional-operator

The question is very simple, but I just could not find the answer!

Why doesn't

```
return x == 0? "" : "Hello"
```

compile but

```
return x == 0 ? "" : "Hello"
```

does?

This is really weird because all the other operators don't need an extra white space. e.g.

```
let x = 1+1
let y = 1 + 1
```

are the same.

I think it has something to do with optionals. But when you use a `?` operator on a variable, it must be used like this:

```
let s: String? = nil
let x = s?.startIndex
```

I mean it must follow another operator, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I think it has something to do with optionals.

It does. The documentation on [operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID418) says:

> There is one caveat to the rules [regarding whitespace around operators]. If the `!` or `?` predefined operator has no whitespace on the left, it is treated as a postfix operator, regardless of whether it has whitespace on the right. To use the `?` as the optional-chaining operator, it must not have whitespace on the left. To use it in the ternary conditional (`?` `:`) operator, it must have whitespace around both sides.

Comment: "To use it in the ternary conditional" may be confusing. "it" is the `?` of the ternary conditional operator _itself_. TLDR you can actually use optional-chaining in a ternary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm pretty sure (as you presumed) the problem is with optionals.

I prefer to write my ternary operators like this...

```
let num = (isTrue) ? (1) : (0)
```

Of course, you can choose what's in the parentheses, whether it's simply a literal (as shown) or not.