# How can I implement a custom error throwing syntax in swift?

Tags: swift, error-handling, syntax, syntax-error

I want to implement the following:

```
throwingFunction()??.doStuff()
/*  if throwingFunction throws an error:
     print the error
  else 
    returns an object with the doStuff() Method 
*/
```

```
throwingFunction()??
/*
 if an error is thrown, 
    prints the error.  
 else 
    execute the function without errors. 
*/
```

I'm not sure where to look in the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift) for examples on how `do, try, catch` were implemented.  The [Swift error docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) explain how to use error handle methods that are already implemented.  To be clear, I want to implement custom error handling with the above syntax.

Something like:

```
precedencegroup Chaining {
    associativity: left
}

infix operator ?? : Chaining

extension Result {
    
  // ERROR: Unary operator implementation must have a 'prefix' or 'postfix' modifier
    static func ??(value: Result<Success, Failure>) -> Success? { 
        switch value {
        case .success(let win):
            return win
        case .failure(let fail):
            print(fail.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Error Handling](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) in the Language Guide

Comment: @vadian, please see my updated question.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [`Result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) type? Something like `Result(catching: throwingFunction).map(doStuff).get()` should do the trick.

Comment: So, you want to create your own version of the Swift compiler that does this?

Comment: @Sweeper, updated question.  I'm looking for something like that. Or an example of any implementation of an infex operator that takes takes an error throwing function.

Comment: @MartinR, that is exactly the idea... I updated the question based on your advice.  Now I'm getting this Unary operator error.  I'm kind of stuck.  If you feel up to writing an answer for this, I will upvote it and I'm fairly certain I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a postfix operator which takes a throwing closure as (left) operand. `??` is already defined as an infix operator, therefore you have to choose a different name:

```
postfix operator <?>

postfix func <?><T>(expression: () throws -> T) -> T? {
    do {
        return try expression()
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now you can call

```
let result = throwingFunc<?>
```

or chain it with

```
let result = (throwingFunc<?>)?.doStuff()
```

---

*Previous answer:*

`??` is already defined as an infix operator. For a postfix operator you have to choose a different name, for example:

```
postfix operator <?>

extension Result {
    static postfix func <?>(value: Result) -> Success? {
        switch value {
        case .success(let win):
            return win
        case .failure(let fail):
            print(fail.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call

```
let res = Result(catching: throwingFunc)<?>
```

or chain it with

```
let res = (Result(catching: throwingFunc)<?>)?.doStuff()
```

Comment: I'm trying to think of a way to do `throwingFunc()<?>` instead of `Result(catching: throwingFunc)<?>`

Comment: @ScottyBlades: Better now?

Comment: The first one nails the trailing method... I think maybe I need a separate infix for the chaining...I need to process how the first one works...to think about how the second one will work.

Comment: @ScottyBlades: Can you explain why a second custom (infix) operator is needed? `<?>` returns an optional so that you can chain it with the “built-in” optional chaining.

Comment: I guess I was hoping for a single operator for chaining. I'm okay if there are two separate defined operators: one for chaining (that internally implements optional chaining as well) and one as a trailing independent operator.

Comment: @ScottyBlades: You could define an infix operator `func <?><T, R>(expression: () throws -> T, op: (T) -> R) -> R?` in the same manner, but what would be the advantage over simple orthogonal features?

Comment: I suppose when looking at multiple symbols (3 at this point) it can be confusing enough to require looking at the implementation to understand its functioning.  I think if I were the user, I would look at 3 symbols and I would probably search the code base for `<?>?` and I would find no implementation of it. After I finally figure out <?> is the new operator, then there would be a moment where I accept chaining operators.  However, I think if there was a single symbol operator, I as a user might interpret the ? as chaining and the operator as itself.

Comment: I think that's it... I can just use a single symbol like `*` or `»`

Comment: @ScottyBlades Do note that the first one only works for parameterless functions. Like I said in my answer, to make it work for functions with n parameters, you'd have to write another `<?>` that accepts a function with n parameters. For 1 parameter, for example, it would be `postfix func <?><T, U>(expression: (T) throws -> U) -> U? {`.

Comment: oh yikes.  I didn't think of that.  Your original answer overcomes this. Can you add that?  Perhaps there is a way to pass a tuple?

Comment: @Sweeper, I split this into a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722764/is-not-a-postfix-unary-operator-and-only-infix-operators-may-declare-a-prece)

Comment: @MartinR, can you re-add the Result version of the answer.  That should be seen.  I think there is a lot of value in that.

Answer (score 2):

There is little chance that you can do this, without actually forking apple/swift and creating your own version of the compiler... Here are my attempts:

First, I noticed that the second part of the desired result, `?.doStuff()` looks exactly like a optional chaining expression. I thought I could make a postfix `?` operator that returned an optional. But it turns out, I can't declare an `?` operator at all:

```
postfix operator ? // error
```

So I used a visually similar character - `‽` - instead. The type of a throwing function is `() throws -> Void` and I used `@autoclosure` so that the `{}` can be omitted:

```
typealias ThrowingFunction<T> = () throws -> T

postfix operator ‽
postfix func ‽<T>(lhs: @autoclosure ThrowingFunction<T>) -> T? {
    switch Result(catching: lhs) {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    case .success(let t):
        return t
    }
}

// Usage:
func f() throws -> Int {
    throw URLError(URLError.badURL)
}

// You have to use it like this :(
(try f()‽)
(try f()‽)?.description
```

The `try` could be omitted if the function you are calling takes no arguments:

```
f‽
(f‽)?.description
```

To make functions of other arity work without `try`, you need to create an implementation of `‽` for each arity, which sucks.

But the brackets must be there because of how Swift parses operators :(

Then I tried to make the approach you attempted, with key paths:

```
func ??<T, U>(lhs: @autoclosure ThrowingFunction<T>, rhs: KeyPath<T, U>) -> U? {
    switch Result(catching: lhs) {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    case .success(let t):
        return t[keyPath: rhs]
    }
}

func f() throws -> Int {
    throw URLError(URLError.badServerResponse)
}
```

This seems to be even worse, because you gotta use it like this:

```
try f() ?? \.description
```

You can't omit the `try`,

```
f ?? \.description // type inferencer freaks out, thinks T is ThrowingFunction<Int>
```

nor reduce the spaces on either side of `??` (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553318/why-ternary-operator-in-swift-is-so-picky) for why):

```
try f()??\.description
```

Plus there is this backlash that is an integral part of the keypath syntax, and you can only use it for key paths, not methods. :(

#### Summary

You can't do this because:

- You can't overload `?`
- You can't put a `?` right after anything because it will be parsed as optional chaining
- You must write `try`, unless you cater for every arity.

Comment: Not sarcastic at all. I probably would have spent a year of trying stuff to get to where your level of exploration that you did in like 1 hour.  It gave me a few ideas and bread crumbs too.

Comment: @ScottyBlades okay, sorry I doubted you :)

Comment: It looks like it may have given @Martin an idea too. I feel every level of blessed that you guys are down to explore these ideas with me at 5:53AM lol.

Comment: @ScottyBlades: I did not read this before updating my answer, but it seems that the ideas are quite similar.

Comment: @Sweeper, I split this into a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722764/is-not-a-postfix-unary-operator-and-only-infix-operators-may-declare-a-prece).

Answer (score 0):

```
postfix operator *

@discardableResult
postfix func *<Preferred>(expression: ErrorAlt<Preferred>) -> Preferred? {
    switch expression {
    case .preferred(let pref):
        return pref
    case .error(let err):
        print(err.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    case .initializersWereNil:
        print("initializersWereNil")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Here is an example usage.

```
enum TestMeError: Error {
    case first
}

extension Int {
    func printWin() {
        print("we did it!")
    }
}

func testMe() -> ErrorAlt<Int> {
    if true {
        return .error(TestMeError.first)
    } else {
        return .preferred(40)
    }
}

// USAGE
testMe()*
```